# How to distinguish two shooting targets between each other using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

Let me start by saying that I'm a complete amateur in image recognition and I'm trying to complete my first assignment using OpenCV in Python. I'm currently really struggling and therefore I came here for some advice or any help in general that would put me on the right path.

#### What am I currently trying to do:

My goal here is to recognize a shooting target image that user uploads and compare it to one of two shooting target templates (images provided lower). My app is afterward going to calculate this shooting target based on the template it matches and give the user a really accurate score of his shot/shots (based on millimeters from the center of the target). This is just a long goal. For now, I'm just trying to figure out how to distinguish the uploaded target image from the templates I have.

#### Examples of shooting targets:

As I mentioned I have two shooting target templates: [**target 1**](https://i.ibb.co/5FJQYMV/empty-target-big.jpg) and [**target 2**](https://i.ibb.co/bJv7KPJ/empty-target-small.jpg).

The user then uploads a target that must match one of the templates.

[**Example that matches target 1**](https://i.ibb.co/nLPXx6V/cropped-shooting-target-big.jpg)

[**Example that matches target 2**](https://i.ibb.co/YjQZPwv/cropped-shooting-target-small.jpg)

Whenever the uploaded shooting target doesn't match any of the templates, the app should tell the user and not continue with the calculation.

#### What have I done and tried so far:

For starters, I figured it would be beneficial to remove everything from the background and crop the image by the shooting target, and so I did. (I thought if I removed all of the background interference I could easily just compare the two images, but I later found out this actually wouldn't be accurate at all).

After that, I tried to calculate the percentage of the black color to the other color inside the target (without the background), but again found out this wouldn't be accurate since the shooter could shoot through a lot of the black color and then the percentage would fluctuate. Also, I wouldn't be able to tell if it's one of the templates since another completely different shooting target could have the same amount of black color in the middle.

As of comparison of the two images, I tried a lot of ways (histogram, feature matching with brute force, template matching) and neither of those seemed to be accurate nor usable (I could have been doing it wrong tho, that's a possibility).

What I have figured after all of those failures is that possibly the best solution would be to compare the circles inside the shooting target or the numbers inside the black middle circles, but I couldn't figure out how to do so properly.

Do you guys have any idea on how to go about this? I would really appreciate any help or any push towards the solution of my problem. Code examples are highly appreciated and would make my day.

**Best regards.**

Comment: Without too much thinking... it seems to me that the difference is rings 4,5,6. So how about making a mask of just those rings and only looking in the masked area?

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not clear for me. You want to locate the bullets' effects on those borads? or Compute the score? or Uploaded plates have no scores and you want to score them by matching to the ground truths? Can you rephrase the problem?

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. 

Mark Setchell your idea seems really good, but I can't really imagine (codewise) making a mask of those areas in the target image. Could you please explain to me how would you go about that or even better, provide some code example (I know it can be very time consuming, but you would make my day).

Comment: MH304 I will try to explain it in a different way. The first step of my app will be to recognize the uploaded image of the target provided by the user. The app needs to match it to one of the templates. If it doesn't match any of the templates, the app will not continue with calculations. This is the part I'm trying to figure out now. After that, I will try to find the bullet holes on the target image provided by the user and afterward find its distance to the center of the target. And somehow calculate the score of the bullets (score = distance in mm from the center). Is it clear for you now?

Comment: Your links do not work!

Comment: Hey, all of the links seem to be working for me. Are you sure they do not work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The targets seem to differ only in score bands (rings) 4, 5 and 6. So I would try and concentrate on those areas.

I took your sample images and resized them to exactly 500x500 pixels, then I measured the radius from the centre to the outside edge of band 4 (which was 167 px) and to the edge of band 6 (which was 95 px). So the outer limit of the area of interest is 167/500, or 0.33xW and the inner limit is 95/500, or 0.19xW where W is the width of the enclosing rectangle.

So, you can draw that mask like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Define width/height of target in pixels
W = 300

# Make mask, white for area of interest, black elsewhere
mask = np.zeros((W,W),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, (W//2,W//2), int(0.33*W), 255, -1)  # White outer circle
cv2.circle(mask, (W//2,W//2), int(0.19*W), 0, -1)    # Black inner circle
```

That gives you this mask:

[image]

You can now calculate, say, the mean of all pixels within that mask using:

```
maskedMean = cv2.mean(YourImage, mask)
```

and only pixels that are white within the mask will contribute to the mean.

Here is the mask placed beside one of your targets:

[image]